# Use AppDelegate in today extension

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I'm trying to build an today extension for my app.

I'm using `CoreData` and `NSFetchedResultsController` and get the following error:

> Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'

In this line of code:

```
var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate.
```

Does someone know how to solve this error / use AppDelegate in the today extension and would like to help me?

Comment: Do you have the proper import statements?

Comment: Did you rename your applicaiton delegate to something different from AppDelegate?

Comment: What do you mean with proper import statements @milo526 (import AppDelegate isn't working). No I don't rename my application delegate (I don't really know how to do this).

Comment: Did you import UIKit & Foundation?

Comment: Yes I imported UIKit & Foundation.

Comment: I am experiencing same problem. Have you found the solution? I am trying to add extension to my existing project, and share the existing Core Data database. We get same problem with you. So, how do you fix the problem?

Comment: Same problem faced here as mentioned by @RobertYiJiang. Could anyone fix the same. Does it require some project setting ?

Answer (score 2):

A Today Extension isn't an application, so UIApplication and AppDelegate aren't available.  I'm not for sure what you are trying to do with the AppDelegate, but extensions do have a [NSExtensionContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSExtensionContext_Class/) available by calling:

```
 self.extensionContext
```

Comment: I'd like to use the NSFetchedResultsController to use CoreData.

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController isn't tied to a UIApplicationDelegate.  If you want to use it in your today extension, just you just use it in TodayViewController. I'm guessing in your application, you use NSFetchedResultsController in your AppDelegate to get the results from CoreData.  If you want to share this code between your app and the extension, you will need to move this code out of AppDelegate and in to a framework that can be used by both the app and the extension.